# Spring: @Configuration vs non-@Configuration classes

Tags: java, spring

В [документации](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java-further-information-java-config) приведен такой пример:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public ClientService clientService1() {
        ClientServiceImpl clientService = new ClientServiceImpl();
        clientService.setClientDao(clientDao());
        return clientService;
    }

    @Bean
    public ClientService clientService2() {
        ClientServiceImpl clientService = new ClientServiceImpl();
        clientService.setClientDao(clientDao());
        return clientService;
    }

    @Bean
    public ClientDao clientDao() {
        return new ClientDaoImpl();
    }
}
```

И сказано, что в этом случае будет не 2 экземпляра `ClientDAO`, а один. И связано это с тем, что `ClientDAO` - это Singleton и классы помеченные `@Configuration` по умолчанию используют `CGLIB` proxy.

Мне интересно, а что будет, если класс `AppConfig` будет помечен @Component вместо @Configuration? Или Spring использует прокси для всех компонентов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Связано это с тем, что все бины в Spring - это одиночки по умолчанию. Цитата оттуда же:

> in Spring, instantiated beans have a singleton scope by default

А CGLIB - это способ, с помощью которого Spring добивается в данном случае возврата одного и того же экземпляра при каждом вызове метода.

CGLIB - это аббревиатура от Code Generation Library. Без кодогенарации не удалось бы перехватить вызовы метода внутри класса. Обычные JDK Dynamic proxy позволяют перехватывать только "внешние" вызовы.

Comment: Это понятно. Вопрос в том, что будет если класс не будет помечен @Configuration? Будут ли в этом случае использоваться CGLIB или JDK proxies?

Comment: Тогда в методе `clientService1` вместо бина `ClientDao` вы получите обычный экземпляр класса `ClientDaoImpl`. При каждом вызове метода `clientDao` новый.